# Oracle SQL to extraction of human names like Nltk

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a SQL/Regex or some advance function where we can extract human names for a columns that has around 2 million rows? some thing like NLTK

below is my sample. In the below I wanted to extract only human names (i.e.) filter companies **. Like these I have 2 million mixed with real companies and human names

```
KAREN STRAUSS
KASEY NEMELKA
KATHLEEN MCMAHON
KATHRYN HOCKADAY
KATHRYN HOLAHAN
KATIE NELSON
**KATHERINE KACENA CONSULTING**
KATHY ATKINS
KATRINA GRANT
KATY DYER
KATY G TACKES
**KAUFFMAN S TRANSPORT LLC**
KATHERINE MAGPANTAY
KATHERINE VENTURA
KATHRYN RUANO
JORGE DANIEL MUSCIA
JOSE MANUEL ROSALES SANTEROS
JOSE MANUEL VILAS CARR
JOSEPH H WILNER
```

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far and also provide some input and output. It will be helpful to check.

Comment: As far as I know, Oracle doesn't contain anything like that. If you had a list of names (stored in a table), then you could check whether rows in your table (you posted) contains human names. Otherwise, I think not. Perhaps someone else knows better.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  Human names are too variable.  After all, is "John Deere" the name of a company.  Or is it the name of a person?  Or both?

You can construct special purpose logic for your data.  It will take time to develop but something like this:

```
regexp(lower(name), '\s(consult|llc)')
```